# Why does the 'then' part in async test fail in jest?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, aws-amplify

**Component:**

```
export const fetchList = () => {
  return API.get(AMPLIFY_ENPOINTS.default, API_URLS.list, { response: true });
}

const List: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const setError = useError();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchList()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response && response.data?.length) {
          dispatch(setList(response.data));
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      });
  }, [])
}
```

**Test:**

```
it('should fetch list', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <List />
    </Provider>
  );
  API.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mockList }));
  const response = await fetchList();
  console.log(store.getActions(), response); // HERE IS THE ISSUE
});
```

So the `store.getActions()` returns `setError` from `catch` block, why is that? It should return `setList` from `then` block. What am I doing wrong? `response` variable returns `mockList` just fine.

**Edit**
The error it returns is `API not configured`, I'm using aws amplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchList` is called when the component is mounted, mocked `API.get` doesn't affect the first time it's called, and second call doesn't do anything. It's a bad practice to mock methods by assigning a spy to them because they cannot be restored after a test.

The problem with `fetchList` is that it cannot be spied or mocked because it's used in the same module it's defined. The promise it creates in `useEffect` cannot be chained, promises need to be flushed in order to avoid race condition.

It can be:

```
  let flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));

  jest.spyOn(API, 'get').mockResolvedValue({ data: mockList });

  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <List />
    </Provider>
  );

  await flushPromises();

  expect(store.getActions())...
```